# Entity Framework 6.0 + Encrypt Connection String

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, encryption

This question may be repeated but we were not able to find a good solution.

Our project uses EF 6.0 & C# and targeted for .NET 4.0 and above and finally SQL Server 2012.

The project works fine without. But have few queries on the EF connection string and the way it stores.

1. How to read the encrypted connection string stored in the app.config to be read in the EF's context.cs file.
2. We added the following code to read encrypted connection string, it works but to an extent only i.e. till we don't add the a new stored procedure.

   ```
   public MCMS_II_LogEntities() 
       // : base("name=MCMS_II_LogEntities") //Original
       :base( GetConnectionString())
       {
       }

   public static string GetConnectionString()
   {
       string connString = new System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder
       {
           Metadata = "res://*",
           Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient",
           ProviderConnectionString = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
           {
               InitialCatalog = "<Catalog Name>",
               DataSource = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataSourceAddress"].ToString(),
               IntegratedSecurity = false,
               MultipleActiveResultSets = true,
               UserID = "<LOGIN ID>",                 // User ID such as "sa"
               Password ="<PASSWORD>",               // hide the password
           }.ConnectionString
       }.ConnectionString;
       return String.Format(connString);
   }
   ```
3. Once we add the new stored procedure or function to the EF model, the above coded added will be removed.

Query

1. What is the best practice to achieve this?
2. How to address this issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What's the role of stored procedures and functions in this?

Comment: @GertArnold there is no specific role of SP and UDF in this. But what I mean is after adding the above piece of code and then we if include another new set of SP or UDF into the EF's library then the above piece of code would disappear and we need to add the it back.

Comment: Then put it somewhere else. A public static method can be stuffed anywhere, preferably in some static utility class.

Answer (score -1):

During the development process you shouldn't encode/encrypt the db connection string, it's a pain in the butt.  The encryption should be done during the deployment/promotion phase not during development.

Test the connection string AFTER you have encrypted it.  Encrypt it when you are ready to move the code to QA or PROD.

Comment: We are testing some functionality of encode/encrypt hence we need to do this exercise. We do understand it's not a good approach while testing but we have no choice at this stage because we need to check all the function of the application if the connection string (i.e. decrypted) is being received properly to the code.